# What is the "caller" command?

Tags: bash, command-line, documentation

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with openbox running on top. I noticed today a command called `caller`, however there is no man page, it does not respond to any input (or --help) and whereis doesn't find it.

Any idea what it is?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run

```
type caller
```

and you will see it is a shell built-in.
Running

```
help caller
```

will show its function, reported as well in bash's manual page. Briefly

> `Return the context of the current subroutine call.`

Comment: Awesome. Not only did I learn what that command does, I also learn the "type" command. Thanks :)

Comment: TIL bash has a built-in `help` command

Comment: Which I could upvote twice for teaching not only the answer but the process as well.

Comment: @Muu, @nibot, @dmckee: also `type type`, `type help`, `help type` and `help help` could be fun to run :)

Comment: by the way, what is `context` of a subroutine call? I tested and inside a subroutine, $(caller 0) returned `9 main ./test5.sh`. Is it like back trace info? (the script name was test5.sh and the subroutine was called in the main body of test5.sh). what is 9 here? EDIT ==> oh I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367029/what-is-a-context-of-a-subroutine. it was the line number!

Comment: Technically, caller is listed in `man 7 bash-builtins`, but it is hidden. For whatever reason, it was left out of the list of builtins in the  'SYNOPSIS' section at the top, (as far as I know, it is the only builtin included in the man_page that isn't in the t-o-c list.) The only way to come across it is to read it (or at least skim over it) top to bottom, or else get lucky while looking up something else. Ive tried the first option, but I'm nowhere near focused enough (usually lose focus somewhere around the `complete` / `compgen`) section. So for those like me, it may as well not be there.

Answer (score 16):

The `caller` is builtin command (not specified by POSIX) appeared in Bash version 3.0 and it returns the context of any active subroutine call. See: [Bash-Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) for more reading.

Syntax:

```
caller [FRAMENUMBER]
```

If *frame number* is supplied as a non-negative integer, it displays the line number, subroutine name, and source file corresponding to that position in the current execution call stack.

Without any parameter, *caller* displays the line number and source filename of the current subroutine call.

Check the following [Simple stack trace at Bash Hackers Wiki](http://web.archive.org/web/20170606145050/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/caller):

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
  local frame=0
  while caller $frame; do
    ((frame++));
  done
  echo "$*"
  exit 1
}

f1() { die "*** an error occured ***"; }
f2() { f1; }
f3() { f2; }

f3
```

Output:

```
12 f1 ./callertest.sh
13 f2 ./callertest.sh
14 f3 ./callertest.sh
16 main ./callertest.sh
*** an error occured ***
```

Here is sample of a decent `die` function to track down errors in moderately complex scripts:

```
{ bash /dev/stdin; } <<<$'f(){ g; }\ng(){ h; }\nh(){ while caller $((n++)); do :; done; }\nf'
```

> For more sophisticated debugging, Bash extended debugging features are available and a number of special parameters that give more detail than caller (e.g. `BASH_ARG{C,V}`). Tools such as [Bashdb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) can assist in using some of Bash's more advanced debug features.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can `read` the output of `caller` into variables, to control how its output is formatted:

```
stacktrace() {
  local frame=0 LINE SUB FILE
  while read LINE SUB FILE < <(caller "$frame"); do
    echo "${SUB} @ ${FILE}:${LINE}"
    ((frame++))
  done
}
```

Demo:

```
$ cat /tmp/caller.sh 
#!/bin/bash

stacktrace() {
  local frame=0 LINE SUB FILE
  while read LINE SUB FILE < <(caller "$frame"); do
    printf '  %s @ %s:%s' "${SUB}" "${FILE}" "${LINE}"
    ((frame++))
  done
}

die() {
  echo "$*"
  stacktrace
  exit 1
}

f1() { die "*** an error occured ***"; }
f2() { f1; }
f3() { f2; }

f3

$ bash /tmp/caller.sh
*** an error occured ***
  die @ /tmp/caller.sh:13
  f1 @ /tmp/caller.sh:17
  f2 @ /tmp/caller.sh:18
  f3 @ /tmp/caller.sh:19
  main @ /tmp/caller.sh:21
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a shell builtin command: `man bash` (Then search for 'caller')
It can be used to print a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks though I picked enzotib's answer as he also taught me 'type'. Many thanks though :)