# function's calling context in zsh: equivalent of bash `caller`

Tags: shell, zsh, function, debugging

In bash, I can write:

```
caller 0
```

and receive the [caller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250533/50557) context's:

- Line number
- Function
- Script name

This is extremely useful for debugging. Given:

```
yelp () { caller 0; }
```

I can then write `yelp` to see what code lines are being reached.

I can implement `caller 0` in `bash` as:

```
echo "${BASH_LINENO[0]} ${FUNCNAME[1]} ${BASH_SOURCE[1]"
```

---

How can I get the same output as `caller 0` in `zsh`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there's a builtin *command* equivalent, but some combination of these four variables from [the zsh/Parameter module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) can be used:

> ```
> funcfiletrace
> ```
>
> This array contains the absolute line numbers and corresponding file
>   names for the point where the current function, sourced file, or (if
>   `EVAL_LINENO` is set) `eval` command was called. The array is of the
>   same length as `funcsourcetrace` and `functrace`, but differs from
>   `funcsourcetrace` in that the line and file are the point of call, not
>   the point of definition, and differs from `functrace` in that all
>   values are absolute line numbers in files, rather than relative to the
>   start of a function, if any.
>
> ```
> funcsourcetrace
> ```
>
> This array contains the file names and line numbers of the points
>   where the functions, sourced files, and (if `EVAL_LINENO` is set) `eval`
>   commands currently being executed were defined. The line number is the
>   line where the ‘`function name`’ or ‘`name ()`’ started. In the case
>   of an autoloaded function the line number is reported as zero. The
>   format of each element is `filename:lineno`.
>
> For functions autoloaded from a file in native zsh format, where only
>   the body of the function occurs in the file, or for files that have
>   been executed by the `source` or ‘`.`’ builtins, the trace information
>   is shown as `filename:0`, since the entire file is the definition. The
>   source file name is resolved to an absolute path when the function is
>   loaded or the path to it otherwise resolved.
>
> Most users will be interested in the information in the
>   `funcfiletrace` array instead.
>
> ```
> funcstack
> ```
>
> This array contains the names of the functions, sourced files, and (if
>   `EVAL_LINENO` is set) `eval` commands. currently being executed. The
>   first element is the name of the function using the parameter.
>
> The standard shell array `zsh_eval_context` can be used to determine
>   the type of shell construct being executed at each depth: note,
>   however, that is in the opposite order, with the most recent item
>   last, and it is more detailed, for example including an entry for
>   toplevel, the main shell code being executed either interactively or
>   from a script, which is not present in `$funcstack`.
>
> ```
> functrace
> ```
>
> This array contains the names and line numbers of the callers
>   corresponding to the functions currently being executed. The format of
>   each element is `name:lineno`. Callers are also shown for sourced
>   files; the caller is the point where the `source` or ‘`.`’ command was
>   executed.

Comparing:

`foo.bash`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
yelp() {
    caller 0
}

foo () {
    yelp
}

foo
```

`foo.zsh`:

```bsh
#! /bin/zsh
yelp() {
    print -l -- $funcfiletrace - $funcsourcetrace - $funcstack - $functrace
}

foo () {
    yelp
}

foo
```

The results:

```bsh
$ bash foo.bash
7 foo foo.bash

$ zsh foo.zsh
foo.zsh:7
foo.zsh:10
-
foo.zsh:2
foo.zsh:6
-
yelp
foo
-
foo:1
foo.zsh:10
```

So, the corresponding values are in `${funcfiletrace[1]}` and `${funcstack[-1]}`. Modifying `yelp` to:

```bsh
yelp() {
    print -- $funcfiletrace[1] $funcstack[-1]
}
```

The output is:

```bsh
foo.zsh:7 foo
```

which is quite close to bash's

```bsh
7 foo foo.bash
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453153/143394), I implemented the following function which works in both `{ba,z}sh`:

```
$ cat yelp
#!/bin/zsh
# Say the file, line number and optional message for debugging
# Inspired by bash's `caller` builtin
# Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453153/143394
function yelp () {
  # shellcheck disable=SC2154  # undeclared zsh variables in bash
  if [[ $BASH_VERSION ]]; then
    local file=${BASH_SOURCE[1]} func=${FUNCNAME[1]} line=${BASH_LINENO[0]}
  else  # zsh
    emulate -L zsh  # because we may be sourced by zsh `emulate bash -c`
    # $funcfiletrace has format:  file:line
    local file=${funcfiletrace[1]%:*} line=${funcfiletrace[1]##*:}
    local func=${funcstack[2]}
    [[ $func =~ / ]] && func=source  # $func may be filename. Use bash behaviour
  fi
  echo "${file##*/}:$func:$line $*" > /dev/tty
}

foo () { yelp; }
yelp
foo
```

The output is:

```
$ ./yelp
yelp::20 
yelp:foo:19
```